# How do I CAST a NUMBER to VARCHAR2 in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, casting

I have a problem with some P-SQL syntax. I have reduced the code sample to its minimum below.

The following works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MyFunction(LINE_ID SMALLINT)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    tmp VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    tmp := CAST(LINE_ID AS VARCHAR2);
    RETURN(tmp);
END MyFunction;
/
```

However, I need to change the LINE_ID parameter to NUMBER(5, 0), after which the following does not work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MyFunction2(LINE_ID NUMBER(5, 0))
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    tmp VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    tmp := CAST(LINE_ID AS VARCHAR2);
    RETURN(tmp);
END MyFunction2;
/
```

The error message in Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.10.09 is

> Error(1,36): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one
>   of the following:     := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":="
>   was substituted for "(" to continue.

How should I write the `CAST` statement in order to make it work with `NUMBER(5, 0)` instead of `SMALLINT`?

Again, this is not the original code but I am looking for a solution that does not deviate too much from the second version and preferably not another function call either. The `VARCHAR2` return type is important as well.

Comment: You could always try to_char.  It might even work.

Comment: Why do you re-invent the wheel? Oracle already has a (much more versatile) function for that: `to_char()`

Comment: This was a conversion from a SQL Server script. Hence my initial "blindness" to this fact. I should have mentioned this in my question so others understood where I was coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify `NUMBER` precision and scale for a function's parameter. Just declare it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MyFunction2(LINE_ID NUMBER)
```

Answer (score 20):

The function you're looking for is `TO_CHAR`:

```
tmp := TO_CHAR(LINE_ID);
```

Comment: The inclusion of precision/scale in the parameter was the original issue but this is a useful suggestion as well.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not in your CAST, but rather in your parameter definition.  From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS657):

You can declare a formal parameter of a constrained subtype, like this:

```
DECLARE
  SUBTYPE n1 IS NUMBER(1);
  SUBTYPE v1 IS VARCHAR2(1);

  PROCEDURE p (n n1, v v1) IS ...
```

But you cannot include a constraint in a formal parameter declaration, like this:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE p (n NUMBER(1), v VARCHAR2(1)) IS ...
```